# Does HttpClient.PostAsync overwrite existing file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on an API that needs to download a file from server A and upload it to server B in the same network. It's for internal use. Each of the files will have multiple versions and will need to be uploaded to server B multiple times and all the versions of the same file will share the same file name.  This is my first time dealing with file manipulation so please bare with me if my question sounds ignorant. Can I use HttpClient.PostAsync for the uploading part in this effort? Or can I just use Stream.CopyToAsync if it's ok to just copy over? Thanks!

Comment: no.  Temp file/folder will be used.  There could be back-end implementations which would over-write... depends on how they name the file when copying and whether they actually want that behavior.

Comment: `PostAsync` does not overwrite anything... It does not even write anything to start with (it may read a file if you are sending file as source)... It is very unclear what you are asking - maybe you expect some formally defined behavior from all servers handling any POST requests that demand them to create file of some sort? Please try to [edit] post to clarify...

Answer (score 2):

`HttpClient.PostAsync` does nothing to do with it. Implementation behind it will do the work. If the back-end does not support this then you cannot do it.

the caller of the `HttpClient.PostAsync` is the client here and you have nothing to do here. If you have access to back-end code of this service, then you can change the behavior of the code.

Comment: You meant overwriting the file? I was just asking what would happen if files of the same name are uploaded using HttpClient.PostAsync. I didn't say I expected overwriting to happen.

Comment: That is totally related with back-end implementation. We cant know